# @Input/@Output check in templates

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, angular-decorator

Is it possible to somehow check in Angular project templates, if there is a `@Input/@Output` defined in template, but not defined in class files? This is what happened recently in our team project: Our colleague did a refactor this week.

He removed/moved a bunch off `@Inputs/@Outputs` but he forgot to update template in some cases.

So we have defined a lot of `@Inputs/@Outputs` in our templates which should't be there. The `tslint` doesn't complain about them at all, so we need to check every single template if there is any `@Inputs/@Outputs` left. At least the `Intellij Idea` gives us warning like `Attribute xy is not allowed here`, but only when the file is open. I'm wondering if there is a way to set-up the `tslint` to give us those warnings?

Comment: Did you try build application? AFAIK it should fail when template uses Input Output which not exist and print why it fails.

Comment: maybe a build with AOT = true would kinda solve the problem. It will not delete automatically the un-used IO but it may show you some errors

Comment: @PatrykBłaziński it doesn't failed.

Comment: If you use those inputs in this way `[someInput]="someVariable"` angular will complain when they don't exist within component. However, with this usage -> `someInput="{{someValue}}"` or `someInput="someValue"` angular will not complain and I don't think there is a way to detect these undefined inputs.

Comment: How are you building your app? 
I removed @Input from component and checked ng build --prod and it fails (angular cli).
@BunyaminCoskuner for angular cli ng build --prod `someInput="{{someValue}}"` also will fail.

Comment: I don't use ng cli, We have custom webpack configuration.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner, yep we are using in some cases `@Inputs` like that `input="Value"` :(

Comment: I think the best way to approach this is incremental. Figure out which inputs from which components are deleted and make a list. When you encounter an usage of that component and if any inputs from the list exists, delete it. It's because, it doesn't do anything when they don't exist (unless there is a directive that defines any input with a name from the list and it is used with the components mentioned above)